# Extract element from HTML with Python's BeautifulSoup library

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking to extract data from Instagram and record the time of the post without using auth.

The below code gives me the HTML of the pages from the IG post, but I'm not able to extract the time element from the HTML.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url_path = 'https://www.instagram.com/<username>'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url_path)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features='lxml')
print(soup)
```

[I would like to extract data from the time element near the bottom of this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXVBR.png)

Answer (score 1):

to extract time you can use html tag and its class :

```
time = soup.findAll("time", {"class": "_1o9PC Nzb55"}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the picture you've shared is a browser inspector screenshot. Although inspecting the code is a good basic guideline on web scraping you should check what BeautifullSoup is getting. If you check the print of `soup` you will see that the data you are looking for its a json inside of a script tag. So your code and any other solution that targets the `time` tag aren't working on BS4. You might try with selenium maybe.
Anyway here goes the BeautifullSoup pseudo-solution using the instagram from your screenshot:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import requests
import time

url_path = "https://www.instagram.com/srirachi9/"
response = requests.get(url_path)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content) 
pattern = re.compile(r"window\._sharedData\ = (.*);", re.MULTILINE)
script = soup.find("script", text=lambda x: x and "window._sharedData" in x).text

data = json.loads(re.search(pattern, script).group(1))

times = len(data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'])
for x in range(times):
    time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][x]['node']['taken_at_timestamp']))
```

The `times` variable its the amount of timestamps the json contains. It may look like hell but its just a matter of patiently following the json structure and indexing accordingly.